# React: reset the input value on space pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new in React. In my react component, I have an input, and i need to reset the value of input to `""` when the user press `space button`.
You can consider the component as following:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class InputReceiver extends Component{

      render(){
          return(
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.props.inputHandler}/>
            </div>);
      }

}
```

Is it true that, i have to make it in the `action`?
but the action does not understand the `input`.

**Point:**
I should not use jQuery.

Comment: are you using redux or pure reactjs

Comment: yes, i am using redux

Comment: where do you want to detect the presence of space button pressed

Comment: in the component. The value of input should be empty ("")

Answer (score 6):

Using React Hooks, you can do the following:

Use the `onKeyDown` attribute on `< input />` field to record each key press. Check if the pressed key is a space ( ASCII value 32 in this case ), and reset the input field.

```
 const InputField = () => {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    
      const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
      };
    
      const handleSpace= (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
          setInputValue("");
        }
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onKeyDown={handleSpace}
          />
          <p>Entered value: {inputValue} </p>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

**Note**: `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Instead, use `KeyboardEvent.key`.
In the above example, it would be:

```
  const handleSpace= (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onKeyDown` to call a function that detect the pressing of spacebar. If spacebar is pressed fire an action that reset the value of input.

Component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import * as action from './path/to/action';

 class InputReceiver extends Component{
      detectSpacePresent = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            this.props.changeInputValue('');
        }
      }
      render(){
          return(
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.props.inputValue} onChange={this.props.inputHandler} onKeyDown={this.detectSpacePresent}/>
            </div>);
      }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    inputValue: state.inputValue;
  }          
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeInputValue: bindActionCreator(action, dispatch);
  }          
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InputReceiver);
```

Action

```
export function changeInputValue(val) {
  return {type:'CHANGE_INPUT_VALUE', data: val}
}
```

Reducer

```
export const = (state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_INPUT_VALUE': 
        return {inputValue: action.data}
  }

}
```

Comment: @ltamajs It isn't need, since we are making use of mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in the component. Thats the beauty of redux

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to have `redux`. People started taking `redux` for granted. You could simply use a `onChange` handler in the `InputReceiver` component and call the `inputHandler` from it. The example below should explain.

Hope it helps!

```js
class InputReceiver extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value : ''
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
  
  onChange(e){
    const val = e.target.value
    const lastChar = val[val.length - 1] //take only the last character
    if(lastChar === ' ') //check if the last character is a <space>
      this.setState({value: ''}) //if yes, reset value
     else
       this.setState({value: val})//if no, save the value
    this.props.inputHandler && this.props.inputHandler(e)
  }
  
  render(){
      return(
        <div className="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </div>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  inputHandler(e){
    console.log('called inputHandler')
  }
    render(){
      return <InputReceiver inputHandler={this.inputHandler} />
    }
}
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah the best practice would be to not dispatch anything to redux until the onSubmit event of the form, rather than on every onChange.